# Set Input Value based on React State after componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using Axios to perform a GET request and then store the information into the {information} property, and then I store all of that in my state. How can I use setState to set the state of the input fields after the compoenntDidMount()?? I've tried a .then() after the this.props.getItemCredential, but it doesn't work because it's not a standard fetch request?

I've also tried to set the state of the input value like: {this.state.profile.credential.itemArray[0].company} and it returns undefined even though I see it in my redux chrome extension as properly being in the state.

I think the issue is that it's returning undefined cause it cannot change the value of the input until the getItemCredential returns, but then how do I wait for it to finish and then adjust the: this.state.(whatever) for each one?

What my component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextFieldGroup from '../../common/TextFieldGroup';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getItemCredential, getCurrentProfile } from '../../../actions/profileActions';
import Spinner from '../../common/Spinner';


class EditInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            company: '',
            title: '',
            location: '',
            errors: {},
            disabled: false
        }

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItemCredential(this.props.match.params.id)
        this.props.getCurrentProfile()
    }



    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.errors) {
            this.setState({errors: nextProps.errors});
        }
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const itemData = {
            company: this.state.company,
            title: this.state.title,
            location: this.state.location,
        }
    }


  render() {

    const { errors } = this.state;
    const { profile, loading } = this.props.profile;
    const { credential } = this.props.profile;

    let editContent;
    if (profile === null || loading) {
        editContent = <Spinner />
    } else {
        editContent = (
            <React.Fragment>
            <div>
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
<TextFieldGroup 
     placeholder={this.state.company}
     name="company"
     value={this.state.company}
     onChange={this.onChange}
     error={errors.company}
     required
 />
 <TextFieldGroup 
      placeholder="* Job Title"
      name="title"
      value={this.state.title}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      error={errors.title}
      required
 />
 <TextFieldGroup 
      placeholder="Location"
      name="location"
      value={this.state.location}
      onChange={this.onChange}
      error={errors.location}
      required
 />
 <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 text-center my-auto">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button text-center m-auto add-credentials-button mt-4" />
 </div>
 </form>
        </div>
        );
    }


    return (
        <div>
            {editContent}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
EditInfo.propTypes = {
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getItemCredential: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    credential: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    profile: state.profile,
    credential: state.credential,
    errors: state.errors
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addExperience, getExperienceCredential, getCurrentProfile })(withRouter(EditExperience));
```

Here is what my state markup looks like:

```
profile: {
    credential: {
        itemArray: [
            0: {
                title: 'Some entry',
                company: 'Some entry',
                Location: 'some entry'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the axios request I'm making:

```
export const getItemCredential = (id) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setProfileLoading());
  axios.get(`/profile/item-credential/${id}`)
      .then(res => 
          dispatch({
              type: GET_ITEM_CREDENTIAL,
              payload: res.data
          })    
      )
      .catch(err => 
          dispatch({
              type: GET_ERRORS,
              payload: err.response.data
          })   
      );
}
```

Here is what my reducer looks like:

```
import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_LOADING, GET_ITEM_CREDENTIAL } from '../actions/types';



const initialState = {
    profile: null,
    credential: null,
    loading: false
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PROFILE_LOADING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case GET_PROFILE:
            return {
                ...state,
                profile: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
    case GET_ITEM_CREDENTIAL: 
        return {
            ...state,
            credential: action.payload
        }
    default: 
        return state;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you elaborate on "I've tried a .then() after the this.props.getItemCredential, but it doesn't work because it's not a standard fetch request?" What does `this.props.getItemCredential(...)` return? You can change it to return a Promise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried attaching, "this.props.getItemCredential(this.props.match.params.id).then((result) => {this.setState({title: result.title, company: result.company, location: result.location})}; and it says, "Cannot read property .then() of undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `.then` if you change `getItemCredential` so it returns a Promise:

```
export const getItemCredential = (id) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setProfileLoading());
  return axios.get(`/profile/item-credential/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
          dispatch({
              type: GET_ITEM_CREDENTIAL,
              payload: res.data
          });
          return res.data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
          dispatch({
              type: GET_ERRORS,
              payload: err.response.data
          });
          throw err;
      });
}
```

Notice the added `return` in `getItemCredential`. Also, notice that `res.data` is returned from the Promise so that it can be accessed by your component that awaits it. I also re-threw the caught error so that the Promise continues in the rejected state instead of resolving to `undefined`.

Comment: Oh ok now I can do a .then(). Thank you for that. Now my only question is, since I'm returning an array of objects, how would I go about accessing the values and assigning them to the state? I can see the results in the redux chrome application for "credential".

Comment: The Promise needs to resolve to the value, so you need to also return a value from your Promise so it's not just a Promise of undefined. Updated the sample code.

Comment: Hmm. So I can get it to work for the profile object, but not the credential object. Is it cause I'm trying to access the data that's contained in an array? For instance when I try to adjust the input field's "placeholder" value by doing something like: {profile.user}, it'll show the right data. Yet when I try to do, {credential.itemArray[0].title}, it returns, "cannot read itemArray of undefined"

Comment: Tweaked further. Perhaps the `.catch(...)` is happening, in which case you'll still get back an `undefined`; changed it to re-throw. Check your console for an error.

Comment: It's returning the data and storing it in the credential props just fine. I just can't declare it in the input placeholder. Like when I console.log it, the entire data is there. And when I view the redux chrome application it's there. So somehow I'm just not declaring it properly in the input field. Like when I console.log(profile.credential) all the data comes back just fine. But when I do console.log(profile.credential.itemArray[0]), it returns undefined?? Even though the itemArray and all its contents will appear just fine when it's just the profile.credential log.

Comment: Are you accessing `this.state.profile.credential.itemArray[0]` before it's been initialized? Maybe you just need to update your rendering to handle the "this is still loading" state. React isn't going to wait on that; you have to tell it what to show the user while _they're_ waiting.

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you for helping me get it all to work. I'm still super new working with the MERN stack and understanding all it's inner workings. Thank you so much!!